# Hosting a nodejs express site on Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express, mimosa

I created a new NodeJS site based on [the documentation of Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Mimosa.html). It works locally. I set up Windows Azure to pull in the changes of [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/petermorlion/Hourly), which it does correctly.

However, (after enabling errors) I'm getting the [an internal server error](http://hourlee.azurewebsites.net/).

I checked my FTP for the logs, but don't have any. There is a 'Git' folder, but nothing interesting there.

When I change my server.js file to the hello world sample, everything works:

```
var http = require('http')
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

This is my server.js now:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    engines = require('consolidate');

exports.startServer = function(config, callback) {

  var port = process.env.PORT || config.server.port || 1337;
  var app = express();
  var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", server.address().port, app.settings.env);
  });

  app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', port);
    app.set('views', config.server.views.path);
    app.engine(config.server.views.extension, engines[config.server.views.compileWith]);
    app.set('view engine', config.server.views.extension);
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(config.server.base, app.router);
    app.use(express.static(config.watch.compiledDir));
  });

  app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
  });

  app.get('/', routes.index(config));

  callback(server);
};
```

So, has anyone succesfully hosted an Express (or more specifically, the Durandal skeleton for Mimosa) NodeJS site on Windows Azure? Or do you know how or where I can find the internal server error?

Comment: If you get this figured out, I'd love to know the steps it takes to turn a vanilla Mimosa/Durandal app into something hosted with Azure. Sort of like the Heroku steps: http://mimosa.io/about.html#Heroku

Comment: I'm currently working on it (in my free time). I will definitely let you know. Mark's answer got me started on a new path. I'll update when I found the solution.

Comment: @DavidBashford I've got it to work and [blogged](http://petermorlion.blogspot.be/2014/03/getting-mimosa-durandal-app-to-work-on.html) about it extensively. In short, you need to get Azure to pull in the /dist contents and start app.js, not server.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've launched a few express applications on the Windows Azure platform and found that I had several instances of it failing quite silently. I personally have found the approach suggested in this [post](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx) by Jay Harris really helpful as it allows me to import dependencies (npm, bower or other) and run grunt tasks to compile the project etc.

A few things worth noting is that often after a new deploy the updates did not display until restarting the Azure server in the control panel. Sometimes the deploy scripts timed out and I had to check them regularly.

This doesn't exactly answer what's wrong with your code (sorry) but I've posted an [example](https://github.com/chasevida/express-azure) using the method mentioned above that may help. The main deploy files are 'web.config', 'deploy.sh' and '.deployment' as well as your 'package.json' file.

Comment: I've put all the details in a [blog post](http://petermorlion.blogspot.be/2014/03/getting-mimosa-durandal-app-to-work-on.html), but you're correct that the most important bits are the web.config and deploy.sh (.cmd in my case).

Comment: Read through your blog post and looks all good. I haven't used Mimosa but it looks like you could do what I've done with Grunt. In `deploy.sh` after installing the npm packages (with mimosa) you could call a Mimosa (build -omp) command to compile the application into your `/dist` directory. That way you shouldn't have to commit any compiled code to your repo and just keep it clean with dev files.